# Excel Search for a Term, Return the corresponding terms in the array

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, lookup

A Spreadsheet has 5 columns and 600 rows.  In column 1 (by way of example) there are 9 types of virus', all of which are mixed but all consistent in spelling.  The other 4 columns are characteristics of each of those types.

So "virus 1" has an h of 1  an n of 1  an R of 1.5 and was seen in Week 6

and this goes on for 600 rows with virus' 1 through 9 mixed

In a separate work sheet, I'd like excel to pull out all the data for Virus 3.  So it has to search the entire spreadsheet for everything in column 1 called "Virus 3" and return the other 4 values for it.

There's a simple sort cut and paste process, but I cant do that as this has to be a living document.  Each week new data comes in which is mixed, I'd like my minions to cut and paste that new data into the master sheet and then take a look at the 9 other spread sheets I've created along with trend lines which I'd have developed.

Comment: You have for example Virus 1 in several rows and you need to extract all?

Comment: @yass Virus 1 occurs (for example) 70 times in Column 1.  In column 1 its found on row 6, 15, 16, 22, 106 etc.   Id like to extract all the data in columns 2, 3, 4 and 5 which correspond to "Virus 1", setting that data down in 70 rows (by 4 columns) in a separate worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in the new sheet and write in column A the Virus Name (Virus 1 in the whole column more than expected you can delete the empty rows later

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$600,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600=A2,ROW($A$2:$A$600),0),COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600,"<>"&A2)+ROW(A2)-1)-1,2),"")
```

You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time for each formula and then drag it down in the same column

2 at the end represent column 2 in the Sheet1 where you have the Data
 A2:E600 all your Data in initial sheet (5 columns and 600 rows) change it as needed
A2:A600 the first column
If will return the Row of the Virus if found or 0 if not
Countif count the non matching rows
Small will find the smallest corresponding row without 0
Row(A2) to have the smallest nth row for Index to move when you drag it down
Index will return the Value in the same row of the Virus and column 2 for the above formula

```
For column 3 use:  


=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$600,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600=A2,ROW($A$2:$A$600),0),COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600,"<>"&A2)+ROW(A2)-1)-1,3),"")

For column 4 use:  


=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$600,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600=A2,ROW($A$2:$A$600),0),COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600,"<>"&A2)+ROW(A2)-1)-1,4),"") 



For column 5 use:   


=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$600,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600=A2,ROW($A$2:$A$600),0),COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$600,"<>"&A2)+ROW(A2)-1)-1,5),"")
```

When finish copy paste special values for all the Data in another place to keep it from changing when you have new Data

Comment: Wow.. Ok.. let me gove this a run this afternoon to see if it work.  Much appreciated